# prove weak topology is locally convex

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-topology

Prove Banach space X endowed with weak topology is locally convex.

To prove it has local convex base is easy since we can write down the neighborhood explicitly

To question is do we need to prove the space X with weak topology is topological vector space.I don't know how to prove this since the topology is no longer norm topology?

I try to prove it by definition that is prove addition map $+:X\times X \to X$ and scalar are continuous.(it seems not very hard by definition correct?)

Comment: What happens if you try to prove that addition is continuous?

Comment: To show continuous,i.e. $(+)^{-1}(V)$ is open for any open $V$. I try to do it near the origin first taking the simplest version of $V= \{x| |\ell(x)|<\epsilon\}$ then prove for any $(a,b) \in (+)^{-1}(V)$ we need to find $U_a + U_b \subset V$

Comment: By continuity of  $\ell$ there must exist a small neighborhood such that $y\in U_a$ we have $|\ell(y)|$ not very far from $|\ell(a)|$(small than the gap between $|\ell(a+b)|<\epsilon$) similarly for $U_b$ so in the neighborhood still has $|\ell(u+v)|<\epsilon$ that is $U_a+U_b\subset V$

Comment: Similar arguement can hold for finite intersection of the form $V= \{x| |\ell(x)|<\epsilon\}$

Comment: @supinf I'm not sure if there exist some clean proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion yes, since you know have a new topology, you should prove again that the new topology
leads to a topological vector space.

Your attempt in the comments sounds correct to me so far.
Of course, one should also show that the multiplication by a scalar is continuous.